# Unexpected result comparing strings

Tags: php

I have two arrays `$oldInfo` and `$newInfo` where `$oldInfo` is existing data from the database and `$newInfo` is info entered by the user. If one specific field is different between the two I want to enter a new row in the database, if that one field is the same than I just update.

```
if($oldInfo['col'] != $newInfo['col']){
    INSERT INTO ...
}
else
{
    UPDATE WHERE ...
}
```

The problem is that the if statement is always evaluating to true. I put an `echo ... die()` command in the if statement to print out the two values and they both look identical. `Old Info: 38mg/1, 20 New Info: 38mg/1, 20`

Is there something specific about string comparison in PHP I am missing? These values seem to be exactly the same (in fact, $oldInfo is used to prepopulate the form so they should be the same) but the if statement is saying they are not the same.

Comment: Put quotes around the values before you output them.  Are there extra spaces? Try trimming the strings before the comparison.

Comment: array_diff()  is probably better

Comment: We would need more info, but my guess is padding or character encoding. Also, try using [`strcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)`($oldInfo['col'],$newInfo['col')==0` instead.

Comment: echo doens't debug well. Always use var_dump

Comment: Use a `var_dump()` on both values, which'll include type/size information as well. And remember to view the page source if you're doing the output in a browser - spaces/tags will get hidden by the browser leading to "false identical" visuals.

Comment: I always feel like an idiot when the solution is simple. Trim worked like a charm, newInfo had a space at the end that oldInfo did not. Will keep var_dump and strcmp for future reference. Have always used echo/print/system.out.println for debugging before, good to learn a better way for PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try trimming the strings before comparison.  Often when this happens it is because an extra bit of whitespace snuck into one of them.

Answer (score -1):

Something funky might be going on with either PHP thinking it's the number 38, or with encoding.  Try using !== instead of != to force strict equality.

Comment: Probably not the case (different types), but good advice nonetheless. If it were the case, the loose comparison would actually be better.